# Как создать копию ScriptableObject в unity?

Tags: unity3d, ооп

У меня в игре реализована система спелов через ScriptableObject. Каждый спелл имеет свои параметры по типу: частоты каста заклинания, базового урона и т.д. Во время игры некоторые параметры изменяются и естественно, они меняются и в предмете спела, поэтому я хочу копировать спелл и редактировать уже его, чтобы сохранить базовый объект не тронутым. Каким способом это можно сделать максимально быстро и эффективно? Заранее спасибо за помощь.